# cross join acting like inner join, not able to understand where I am wrong?

Tags: mysql

**This is the question and Table:**
Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

| Name | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| Ashley | Professor |
| Samantha | Actor |
| Julia | Doctor |
| Britney | Professor |
| Maria | Professor |
| Meera | Professor |
| Priya | Doctor |
| Priyanka | Professor |
| Jennifer | Actor |
| Ketty | Actor |
| Belvet | Professor |
| Naomi | Professor |
| Jane | Singer |
| Jenny | Singer |
| Kristeen | Singer |
| Christeen | Singer |
| Eve | Actor |
| Aamina | Doctor |

---

**This is my Query:**

```
select dps.Doctor, dps.Professor, dps.Singer, a.Actor from  
(Select dp.Doctor, dp.Professor, s.Singer, row_number() over()ID from  
(select d.Doctor, p.Professor, row_number() over() ID from   
(select Name Doctor, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where Occupation = 'Doctor')d   
cross join
(select Name Professor, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where Occupation = 'Professor')p 
on p.ID=d.ID)dp   
cross join
(select Name Singer, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where Occupation ='Singer')s   
on dp.ID = s.ID)dps   
cross join  
(select Name Actor, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where   Occupation = 'Actor')a   
on dps.ID = a.ID;
```

**The Output I expect:**

```
|  Doctor  |  Professor  |  Singer  |  Actor  |
|  ------  |  ---------  |  ------- | ------- |
|  Aamina  |  Ashley     | Christeen|   Eve   |
| Julia    |  Belvet     |   Jane   | Jennifer| 
|  Priya   |   Britney   |  Jenny   |  Ketty  |
|   NULL   |  Maria      | Kristeen | Samantha| 
|  NULL    |    Meera    |   NULL   |   NULL  |
|   NULL   |    Naomi    |   NULL   |   NULL  |
|  NULL    |   Priyanka  |  NULL    | NULL    |
```

**BUT OUTPUT I GET FOR MY Query:**

```
|  Doctor  |  Professor  |  Singer  |  Actor  |
|  ------  |  ---------  |  ------- | ------- |
|  Aamina  |  Ashley     | Christeen|   Eve   |
| Julia    |  Belvet     |   Jane   | Jennifer| 
|  Priya   |   Britney   |  Jenny   |  Ketty  |
```

I want to know my error in mysql logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the maximum possible rows in your output and left join.

```
with cte as
(
select row_number() over () rn
from OCCUPATIONS
cross join(select occupation,count(*) from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation order by count(*) desc limit 1) s
) 
select cte.rn,d.name as doctor,p.name as professor,s.name 'singer' ,a.name as 'Actor'
from cte
left join (select Name, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where Occupation = 'Doctor')d   on d.id = cte.rn
left join (select Name, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where Occupation = 'Professor')p on p.id = cte.rn
left join (select Name, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where Occupation ='Singer')s on s.id = cte.rn
left join (select Name, row_number() over(order by Name) ID from OCCUPATIONS where   Occupation = 'Actor')a  on a.id = cte.rn
```